How do I change the mirror when building snapcraft
When I build a snapcraft from a yaml file the packages are pulled from http://security.ubuntu.com and http://archive.ubuntu.com.
This makes sense, as I am using the core24 base snap and this is coming from its config in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources.
Now how do I change this so that during the phases Fetching stage-packages another server is used?
Here is an example config:
name: app-simple

base: core24
grade: devel
confinement: strict

apps:
  test:
    command: usr/bin/test

parts:
  test:
    plugin: nil
    source: test
    source-type: local
    build-packages:
      - clang
      - cmake
      - ninja-build
      - libfmt-dev
    stage-packages:
      - libfmt9
    override-build:
      cmake ${CRAFT_PROJECT_DIR} -G Ninja
      ninja test
      mkdir -p "${CRAFT_PART_INSTALL}/usr/bin/"
      cp test "${CRAFT_PART_INSTALL}/usr/bin/test"

Then I run it with lxd and the command:
snapcraft --verbosity debug --debug

This eventually runs:
2024-06-12 22:53:38.005 :: 2024-06-12 22:48:35.023 Fetching stage-packages                                    
2024-06-12 22:53:38.005 :: 2024-06-12 22:48:35.023 Requested stage-packages: ['clang', 'cmake', 'ninja-build', 'libfmt-dev']                                                  
2024-06-12 22:53:38.005 :: 2024-06-12 22:48:35.025 Executing: ['apt-get', 'update']                           
2024-06-12 22:53:38.005 :: 2024-06-12 22:48:39.356 :: Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease                                                                                                       
2024-06-12 22:53:38.005 :: 2024-06-12 22:49:28.433 :: Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease  
2024-06-12 22:53:38.005 :: 2024-06-12 22:49:28.434 :: Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease                                                                                                         
2024-06-12 22:53:38.005 :: 2024-06-12 22:49:28.434 :: Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease                                            

I know I can overwrite the different stages, but all seem to come after the fetch stage.
